# Android Studios Uploading pictures into intern database

Tags: java, android, database

Im trying to develope a function so i can upload pictures into my intern database in Android Studios. Has somebody an idea how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well , first thing you need to add  two button to select picture and to submit upload picture something like ..

```
Button Buttonlog;
Button Buttonbro;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView messageText;
private TextView file-token-name;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
private String upLoadServerUri = null;
private String imagepath=null;
private ImageView imageview;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY = 1;
  @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main15);
   file-token-name=findViewById(R.id.filename);
    file-token-name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Buttonbro = findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
    Buttonbro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Buttonbro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity15.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity15.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY);
                } else {
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            loadGallery();
        }
    });
 progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
    imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);
    upLoadServerUri = "https://www.yoursite.net/upljsonfile.php";
    Buttonlog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String  file1;
   
                    file1=file-token-name.getText().toString();
               
                //Start ProgressBar first (Set visibility VISIBLE)

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Starting Write and Read data with URL
                        //Creating array for parameters
                        String[] field = new String[1];
             
                        field[0] = "file1";
                    
                        //Creating array for data
                        final String[] data = new String[1];
            
                        data[0] = file1;
                       
                        if (!isFinishing()) {
                            PutData putData = new PutData("https://www.yorwebsite.net/post-to-database-file-name.php", "POST", field, data);
                            if (putData.startPut()) {
                                if (putData.onComplete()) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    String result = putData.getResult();
                                    //End ProgressBar (Set visibility to GONE
                                    if (result.equals("Post Succssefl")) {
                                        if (!file1.equals("")) {
                                             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity15.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                           // dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity15.this);
                                           // dialog.setMessage("Uploading File");
                                           // dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                                            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                                            dialog.setMax(100);
                                            dialog.show();
                                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    uploadFile(imagepath);
                                                }
                                            }).start();
                                            if (isFinishing()) {
                                                if (dialog != null) {
                                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                                    dialog = null;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity11.class);
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                                isFinishing();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }); //End Write and Read data with URL
            
        }



    });
}
```

And then our  loadGallery() func

```
    private void loadGallery() {
    Intent choose = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(choose, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY);
}
```

after that you have to allow permission take your image select path something like  ..

```
  public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    assert cursor != null;
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY) {// If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY);
        }  //do something like displaying a message that he didn`t allow the app to access gallery and you wont be able to let him select from gallery
    }
  
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "NewApi"})
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY && data != null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        assert selectedImageUri != null;
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" + imagepath);
        String uriString = selectedImageUri.toString();
        File myFile = new File(uriString);
        String displayName;
        if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
            try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, null, null, null, null)) {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    file-token-name.setText(displayName);
                }
            }
        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
            displayName = myFile.getName();
            file-token-name.setText(displayName);
        }
    }
}
```

now we add our upload file func something like ..

```
 @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file", sourceFileUri);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                    + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int sentBytes=0;
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                sentBytes += bufferSize;
                int progres =(bytesRead * 100 / bytesAvailable);
                new Thread(
                        // do your stuff
                        new publishProgress(progres)
                ).start();
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" C:/xamp/wamp/fileupload/uploads";
                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity15.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity11.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity15.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity15.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    } // End else block
}
```

fainaly .. our tow php file one to upload our file"upljsonfile.php",And second to post our file name to database "post-to-database-file-name.php", like code bellow ..

the first file "upljsonfile.php" :

```html
<?php
 $response = array();
if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES['file']['error']) {
 $response["code"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "failed to move uploaded file";
        echo json_encode($response);
 }

$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;

$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filePath = "uploadfiles/$fileName";


// Open temp file
$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");

if ($out) {
  // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
  $in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

  if ($in) {
    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
          fwrite($out, $buff);

  } else

 $response["code"] = 2;
 $response["message"] = "Oops!  Failed to open input Stream error occurred.";
 echo json_encode($response);
  @fclose($in);

  @fclose($out);

  @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
} else

   $response["code"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! Failed to open output error occurred.";
        echo json_encode($response);


// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
  // Strip the temp .part suffix off
  rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}
  $response["code"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "successfully uploaded";
        echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

and the second file "post-to-database-file-name.php :

```html
<?php
require "databasemob.php";
$db = new DataBase();
if (isset($_POST['file1']) ) {
    if ($db->dbConnect()) {
        if ($db->filenamepost("filename", $_POST['file1'])) {
            echo "Post Succssefl";

        } else echo "Some error !";
    } else echo "Error: Database connection";
} else echo "All fields are required";
?>
```

and the databasemob.php :

```html
<?php
require "DataBaseConfig.php";

class DataBase
{
    public $connect;
    public $data;
    private $sql;
    protected $servername;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $databasename;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect = null;
        $this->data = null;
        $this->sql = null;
        $dbc = new DataBaseConfig();
        $this->servername = $dbc->servername;
        $this->username = $dbc->username;
        $this->password = $dbc->password;
        $this->databasename = $dbc->databasename;
    }

    function dbConnect()
    {
        $this->connect = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->databasename);
        return $this->connect;
    }

    function prepareData($data)
    {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connect, stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($data)));
    }

        function filenamepost($table,  $file1)
    {
      
        $file1 = $this->prepareData($file1);
    
           $ssq="SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';";
        mysqli_query($this->connect,$ssq);
        $this->sql =
            "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (`file1`) VALUES ('" . $file1 . "')";
        if (mysqli_query($this->connect, $this->sql)) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
     
}
?>
```

last file DataBaseConfig.php :

```html
<?php

class DataBaseConfig
{
    public $servername;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $databasename;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->servername = 'localhost';
        $this->username = 'username';
        $this->password = 'pass@';
        $this->databasename = 'filename';

    }
}

?>
```

this way its work by take ur file name from file Uri from phone and prosses for tow way by uploading file and post file to your database ,, hope it help you :)